# Will outer object be GCed if a class member is KeepAlived in C#?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

see this class:

```
class Outer
{
    private Foo _foo;

    public Outer()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
        GC.KeepAlive(_foo);
    }
}
```

If I create an object of class Outer, will the object be GCed?

Comment: I think you completely misunderstand what KeepAlive() does.  Not sure enough to invest in an answer.  Nothing happens in this code, the object behavior is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you've correctly understood how [`KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) works?

> References the specified object, which
>   makes it ineligible for garbage
>   collection from the start of the
>   current routine to the point where
>   this method is called.

So you're instantiating an instance of `Outer`. The constructor instantiates `_foo` and immediately calls `KeepAlive`. That `KeepAlive` call ensures that `_foo` is not collected in the time between when it was instantiated and when `KeepAlive` was called. As soon as the `KeepAlive` call has completed, `_foo` is eligible for collection.

The instance of `Outer` -- or any other class -- is eligible for collection as soon as it is no longer in use. Even theoretically, the call to `KeepAlive` is irrelevant: it might keep `_foo` alive for *slightly* longer, but it makes no difference to the outer class.

Comment: Indeed. The primary use of KeepAlive being to ensure that a reference to a managed object is not collected when dispatching to unmanaged code, as managed objects referenced in unmanaged code cannot be reliably tracked (and therefore might be collected while a piece of unmanaged code still maintains a reference to the object).

Comment: @Washu: It's a bit broader than that.  Even within 100% managed code, GC.KeepAlive may be necessary if a routine uses parts of an object that would be jinxed if the finalizer for the whole object were to fire.  For example, if an class subscribes to events from a long-lived object, it may be useful to have a wrapper object which will be held by anyone who's interested in keeping the main object alive.  Since events go to the main object, rather than the wrapper, they will not prevent the wrapper from being Finalized.  Thus, it will be possible to clean up events from an abandoned object.

Comment: @Washu: All well and good, with one caveat: if Wrapper.Foo() calls MainObject.Foo() and does nothing else, the wrapper could become eligible for GC and finalization while MainObject.Foo is still running, thus jinxing MainObject.  The remedy is for Wrapper.Foo() to call GC.KeepAlive() on itself after calling MainObject.Foo().